# JBoss 4.2 with AspectJ

Tags: jboss, aop, aspectj

There is a legacy JBoss 4.2 application, in which I would like to add some AOP. My question is what kind of setup do I have to do, in order to be able to use AspectJ LTW?

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I have the exact same question/issue.  How/where does the aspectjrt.jar need to go?

Comment: Hi Eric. Yes, I have resolved this issue. For the moment I am very busy, but I promise to come back with details by the end of this week.